# How to proceed for research on Network security?

Tags: ipv4, security, network-core, network-discovery

> It may out of scope but I have to research on Network security. I have
>   worked on Signal Processing in Time-Frequency down during Post
>   Graduation research and have few publication. Now my interest has been
>   changed to networking. I was qualify CCNA certification and complete
>   study of CCNP route. Now I wanna to apply PhD in Network Security.
>   Please suggest me some possible online/Offline resource and how to
>   prepare for PhD?

Comment: A lot depends of course on where you live, but in any case, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. The community has decided that certification/education questions are off topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. If you have the required reptutation (currently 20+) please ask in our dedicated [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/) where you are free to ask a wider variety of questions.